# Can I specify how often a non-delivery report will get sent for a mail on the mail queue, Exim4

Tags: email

I am using Exim4 as my primary mail transfer agent.

I have sent a message and it currently resides on exims mail queue and will continue to be there for at least 5 days.

I believe a Non-Delivery report will be sent to me once every 24 hours telling me that my mail has not been sent.

Can I ask exim to send a Non-Delivery Report to me once every 6 hours instead of once every 24 hours?

So in a 24 hour period I would like to receive 4 non-delivery reports from my exim server telling me my mail is undelivered.

Is it possible to do this? Any links or information surrounding this topic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the `delay_warning` setting. When a message is delayed, Exim sends a warning message to the sender at intervals specified by this option.

This needs to be added to exim's configure file:

```
delay_warning = 4h:8h:24h
```

The first message is sent after 4 hours, the second after 8 hours, and the third one after 24 hours. After that, messages are sent every 16 hours, because that is the interval between the last two times on the list. If you set just one time, it specifies the repeat interval.

See the [exim documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html) for more details.